# Division operator taken literally in stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to perform a simple division:

```
div
  height 20px / 2

/* Compiles to: */
div {
  height: 20px/2
}
```

I was able to get it to work using multiplication though... why does division not work?

```
div
  height 20px * .5

/* Compiles to: */
div {
  height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `/` within a property value, you must wrap with parens. Otherwise the `/` is taken literally (to support CSS line-height). See: [`Multiplicative: * / %`](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/operators.html#multiplicative---) in the Operator section of the Stylus Docs.

```
div
  height (20px / 2)

/* Compiles to: */
div {
  height: 10px;
}
```